# How to properly use CSP with Angular 16?

Tags: angular, content-security-policy

Following the Angular security guide I'm attempting to use CSP in my Angular application but I'm having difficulties with two parts.

First any styles included via the `angular.json` configuration file seem to become inlined when running `ng build`. Second, any `link` tags that import styles also seem to be loaded and inlined by `ng-build`.

For example. I have this section in my `angular.json` file:

```json
"styles": [
    "src/styles.scss"
]
```

And the following `<link>` in my index.html:

```html
<link href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat&family=Open+Sans:ital,wght@0,300;0,400;0,600;0,700;0,800;1,300;1,400;1,600;1,700;1,800&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
```

After running `ng build` the `index.html` file becomes this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head><link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin="">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Site</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <!-- TODO: REPLACE BY ACTUAL HTTP HEADER (AND ACTUAL NONCE) -->
  <script>
    myRandomNonceValue = 'randomNonceGoesHere';
  </script>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self'; style-src 'self' fonts.googleapis.com 'nonce-randomNonceGoesHere'; script-src 'self' 'nonce-randomNonceGoesHere'; font-src  https://fonts.gstatic.com data:;">
    
    <style type="text/css">
        <!-- Content from fonts.googleapis.com is added here -->
    </style>
    
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
    <style>
        <!-- Content from styles.scss is added here -->
    </style>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.dd15db77dac66d40.css" media="print" onload="this.media='all'"><noscript><link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.dd15db77dac66d40.css"></noscript></head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
<script src="runtime.02ee8844f7593507.js" type="module"></script><script src="polyfills.57c3a9c9c943caee.js" type="module"></script><script src="main.9eaed3d82b050a64.js" type="module"></script>

</body></html>
```

At runtime this results in the browser complaining about the inline style-elements not having the csp-nonce added to them. The styles for the components is added correctly using the nonce, but these inline ones aren't.

The only way I got this to work is to allow unsafe, but that pretty much removes the whole nonce-usefulness.

It seems like I'm missing something as this should just work right? How can I make Angular not inline these `<style>` tags but instead just make it download them?